# VLOOKUP only returning 1 or 0 when row is matched

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a vlookup I just made

`=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,3,FALSE)`

It matches 1 column in 1 sheet to another in the other sheet. When I test it out by changing it to: `=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,1,FALSE)` It returns the same value that I am searching for.

And further if i test it with:

`=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,2,FALSE)`

It returns the corresponding value from sheet1 that I need.

BUT what I really need is column 3 which is a number, and when I use:

`=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,3,FALSE)`

The only numbers I get are 1 or 0. even though those are not the correct numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are only looking to return the value in the 3rd column then there would not be much need to search in a range that goes out to column M. You could condense you range to `Sheet1!$B$3:$D$591`. 

Without seeing your data it is a little hard to say but if you change the value of B3 in Sheet1 to the value in D5 does the vlookup return the correct value?

Comment: What column letter contains the values you want to retrieve?  Column C (i.e. "column 3"), column D (3rd column in lookup range), something else?

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question - use `=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,2,FALSE)` - the 2 refers to the column with the "lookup array" which is Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591, so column 2 of that is Sheet1!$C$3:$C$591

Answer (score 0):

> It returns the same value that I am searching for.

Because you have set the column index to "1", which is the collumn being searched by the VLOOKUP formula.

> BUT what I really need is column 3 which is a number, and when I use:
>
> =VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$591,3,FALSE)

Please post your workbook, or an example of the workbook data and we can help. Without seeing your data, it's impossible to say.